# MYSQL: list all sales people who represent members who are not in california

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables, one for sales people and one for members of bands. I need to list the **`sales people who represent members who ARE NOT in california`**

**salespeople** table

```
 +---------+-----------+----------+
 | salesid | firstname | lastname |
 +---------+-----------+----------+
 |       1 | Bob       | Bentley  |
 |       2 | Lisa      | Williams | 
 |       3 | Clint     | Sanchez  |
 |       4 | Scott     | Bull     |
 +---------+-----------+----------+
```

**members** table

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| salesid | firstname | lastname  | region |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|       2 | Bryce     | Sanders   | NC     |
|       3 | Marcellin | Lambert   | VA     |
|       3 | Caroline  | Kale      | VA     |
|       1 | Kerry     | Fernandez | VA     |
|       2 | Roberto   | Alvarez   | IN     |
|       1 | Mary      | Chrisman  | IN     |
|       3 | Carol     | Wanner    | TX     |
|       2 | Warren    | Boyer     | TX     |
|       1 | Bonnie    | Taft      | VT     |
|       3 | Terry     | Irving    | GA     |
|       2 | Louis     | Holiday   | IL     |
|       2 | Michelle  | Henderson | GA     |
|       3 | Bobby     | Crum      | VT     |
|       2 | Tony      | Wong      | ONT    |
|       2 | Vic       | Cleaver   | VT     |
|       1 | Frank     | Payne     | NY     |
|       1 | Roberto   | Goe       | OH     | 
|       1 | Jose      | MacArthur | CA     |
|       3 | Doug      | Finney    | GA     |
|       3 | Brian     | Ranier    | ONT    |
|       2 | William   | Morrow    | NY     |
|       2 | Aiden     | Franks    | TX     |
|       2 | Davis     | Goodman   | OH     |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

I have tried

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, b.region FROM salespeople a LEFT JOIN members b ON 
b.region != "CA";
```

which returns about 88 records because of the fact that all 4 sales people represent every member. which leads me to my next question, **`I also need  to list all salespeople who do not represent any members who are located in California`**. What would be the difference in my query?

Comment: You are **not** using your `Primary` and `Foreign` keys for `JOIN`.

Comment: @PM77-1 so you mean like this? 

SELECT b.firstname, b.lastname, a.firstname, a.lastname, a.region FROM members a LEFT JOIN salespeople b ON a.salesid = b.salesid WHERE a.region != "CA" ORDER BY a.region;

Comment: yeah i tried and i got 22 records which makes more sense. now how would i alter the query to list the salespeople who dont represent any members who are located in california

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.firstname, b.lastname, GROUP_CONCAT(a.region) regions
FROM members a 
LEFT JOIN salespeople b ON a.salesid = b.salesid 
GROUP BY b.firstname,b.lastname
HAVING NOT FIND_IN_SET("CA", regions);
```

***[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/122e41/7)***

Answer (score 0):

This will provide you the sales people who will not represent CA.

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, b.region FROM salespeople a LEFT JOIN members b 
ON a.salesid = b.salesid where b.region != "CA" 
and b.salesid NOT IN (select c.salesid from members c where b.region = "CA");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname ,b.region
FROM salespeople a, members b
WHERE a.salesid = b.salesid
AND a.salesid NOT IN(
  SELECT DISTINCT c.salesid
  FROM members c
  WHERE c.region = 'CA'
)
GROUP BY a.salesid,b.region
HAVING b.region !='CA'
```

This answer is not using join, hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  a.firstname, 
  a.lastname, 
  b.region 
FROM salespeople a 
  LEFT JOIN members b ON a.salesid = b.salesid 
WHERE b.region != "CA"
```